# How to use variable in simple html dom

Tags: php, variables, simple-html-dom

Im scraping some urls with simple html dom. The urls change so I used them as a variable like this:

```
var URL = $('input').val();
document.getElementById("iframe").src = "proxy.php?url="+ URL;
```

The url would be:

```
proxy.php?url=http://somewebsite.com
```

In proxy.php I fetch this variable like this:

```
$url = $_GET['url'];
```

It al works good. So now I would like to send a second variable, a div that is changing. How do I send this variable to my php file "proxy.php"? I tried something like this but it doesn't work:

The url:

```
proxy.php?url=http://somewebsite.com?variable=the-variable
```

In my php file:

```
$variable = $_GET['the-variable'];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   // try this. add & before variable
   proxy.php?url=http://somewebsite.com&variable=the-variable
```

Answer (score 1):

You try to fetch the variable by its value, in your case the variable name is `variable` and its value is `the-variable`. Use the variable name instead the value in your php file: `$_GET['variable']`

Also, if you have multiple variables in your URL you have to seperate them by `&` e.g: `http://host/your.php?var1=value1&var2=value2`